# Python os.remove(...) string manipulation

Tags: python, filepath

Code snippet:

```
img_file_rm = scaned_pics_path + media_path + i       #putting togehter some path parts
print("1",img_file_rm) # output-> path like it should be  e.x. C:\\name\\folder1\\pic.bmp
os.remove(img_file_rm) # output-> path it is [error]  e.x. C:\\\\name\\\\folder1\\\\pic.bmp
```

So you see `os.remove()` somehow adds extra `\`s

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden:C:\\\\name\\\\folder1\\\\pic.bmp
```

Comment: Your path looks wrong, there are two many backslashes. `r"C:\\name\folder1\pic.bmp"` should be correct in case of a raw-string or `"C:\\\\name\\folder1\\pic.bmp"` escaped.

Comment: Hey Sven thank you for the fast answer.

C:\\name\\folder1\\pic.bmp works fine in windows

x = "C:\\name\\folder1\\pic.bmp works fine in windows"
but after os.remove(x) 
The String looks like this ->C:\\\\name\\\\folder1\\\\pic.bmp

Comment: I'd encourage you to use more advanced methods for forming full file paths like Pathlib or at least using os.path.join to join parts of a path together rather than using string concatenation.

Comment: i will have a look at both @scotty3785

Comment: @scotty3785 Pathlib looks like it be lifting up my life. I will Try it and give you an update on my Code. My current way seems really messy.

Answer (score 1):

I recoded my Code with Pathlib and now it works. The Problem was the mess, with strings, os.join, "/","//",r"..." and so on.